# Is it normal to seed database application through API call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, laravel, random-seed

My question is about what the standard in my case?

I have two applications, one for managing users and the other one for managing another stuff.
I want to seed the second application with data, to seed it in a correct way I must have a user data on the first application.

So, Is it standard when I seed the second application to call API to create the user data or make another seed on the first application and provide this seeded data to the second seeder?

Comment: Did you found an answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, No :(